# select a table from variable explorer using Sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a data frame I read into python using pandas.
I would like to use sql to get information about this table.
The name of the table is data and it is in the variable explorer.
I tried using the following code

```
   connection = sqlite3.connect("company.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT closing_rate from data")
```

I get the following error  "no such table: data"
Is there a way to use sql on tables saved in the variable explorer without creating them in the database?

I tried installing pandasql which I read can help in this situation but I get an error message  No module named 'pandasql'

Comment: What's a variable explorer?

Comment: Hi Lee, unfortunately, your question is not quite clear to me. Do you have your data already in a pandas DataFrame or do you want read an sql database into pandas? Please elaborate your question.